# Eliminate code on Client-side in React Js

Tags: reactjs, optimization, next.js, client-server

I need help in one of my project. (React based)

scenario : In my project file A has code in which some portion of code utilise on SSR and some on CSR.

Problem facing : when bundling the project(app-shell), in CSR also i am seeing the SSR code.

Goal: Eliminate SSR code when render on CSR. **(react based solution)**
similar behaviour  like vercel nextjs:  https://next-code-elimination.vercel.app/

please do let me know how to achieve or any reference link would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

- used a flag isServer in webpack config and set it to false as default.
- determine on the basis of proess.isServer
- Tried [AST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) approach to eliminate the server side code